# How can I tell if someone is getting into my device remotely

Tags: applications, security

I think someone is spying on me. How can I tell if someone read my messages for pink my phone calls or downloading pictures to their equipment or from cuz I have Android IP address pop up on my Google account every now and again that isn't mine

Comment: Have you used Android emulator once for a while? Did you notice any visible suspicious activities other than assuming if someone is spying you? Otherwise, change your Google account password first and observe the result.